# Why can't I access the [0][0] position of my 2 dimensional array created with 'new Array' constructor?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a function that receives a height and a width and creates a 2 dimensional array. My function seems to be achieving this but then when I try to change position [0][0] of the created array it changes all first positions of my inner arrays (see snippet for more clarity).

What am I doing wrong?

```js
function createArr(height, width) {
  return new Array(height).fill(new Array(width).fill(1));
}

const myArr = createArr(3,2)
console.log(myArr)
//Expected output: [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]
myArr[0][0] = 5;
console.log(myArr)
// Expected output: [[5,1],[1,1],[1,1]]
// Real output: [[5,1],[5,1],[5,1]]
```

Comment: Umm, I think `createArr(3,2)` should supposed to be `createArr(2,2)` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the same array reference created with `new Array(width).fill(1)` is being passed for all heights. Hence if you change any array, it seems like all arrays have change but actually its the same array whose reference is being passed for all `height`. Hence for every `height` you need to use `new Array()` constructor to create separate arrays for each `height`

```
function createArr(height, width) {
  const arr = [];
  for(let i=0; i<height; i++){
    // You need to create new array for every height
    arr[i] = new Array(width).fill(1);
  } 
  return arr;
}

const myArr = createArr(3,2)
console.log(myArr)
//Expected output: [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]
myArr[0][0] = 5;
console.log(myArr)
// Actual output: [[5,1],[1,1],[1,1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const val = 1;
function createdArr(R,C) { 
var arr = Array(R);
  for (var i = 0; i < R; i++) {
      arr[i] = Array(C).fill(val);
  }
  return arr;
}
var ary = createdArr(3,2);
console.log(ary);
ary[0][0]=5;
console.log(ary);
```

**UPDATE**: Little late to post, @Rishabh has already answered with reason.